# Exercising my treaty rights

Tags: immigration, family

My sister and I are both eligible for British passport due to our father having been British.  We live in South Africa with my mum.  We would like to move to Ireland within the next 18 months, I am 16 years old.  I would like to know if I can bring my mum under my treaty rights? and what do I have to do?

Comment: Was your father *born* in Britain?  If not, he will be have been "British by descent", and you will *not* be eligible for a British passport.

Comment: Your other problem is that in the event of a no-deal Brexit, British passport holders may not be able to move to Ireland after 29th March next year (less than six months away).

Comment: @MartinBonner Irish citizens' status in the UK is independent of the EU.  Is the same not true of British citizens' status in Ireland?

Comment: @phoog Irish citizens' status in the UK is about the UK never really having got round to accepting Irish independence.  I *believe* the Republic of Ireland is quite happy with the idea that the UK is a separate country (except for Northen Ireland - even if they gave up the claim to NI as part of the Good Friday Agreement).  It is possible that RoI will admit British citizens - but it is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks for the clarification. I would also note that in your earlier comment, "born in Britain" is somewhat oversimplified; Northern Ireland, the Channel Islands, and the Isle of Man are included, and there is also the "crown service" exception.

Comment: @phoog Yes.  When I said "Britain", that was sloppy wording for "United Kingdom". I didn't know about CI+IoM, and I forgot about "crown service" to.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know if I can bring my mum under my treaty rights?

On its face, EU free movement law gives no right to the non-EU parent of an EU citizen unless the *parent* is dependent on the *child,* which is highly unlikely if you are sixteen.

There are, however, court cases suggesting that if the child is a minor then refusing to grant residence to the non-EU parent is an impermissible restriction on the child's right of free movement.  See, for example:

- [Think of the children: the ECJ clarifies the status of non-EU parents of EU citizen children living in their own Member State](http://eulawanalysis.blogspot.com/2017/05/think-of-children-ecj-clarifies-status.html)
- [Chavez Vilchez et al v. Sociale Verzekeringsbank et al](https://curia.europa.eu/jcms/upload/docs/application/pdf/2017-05/cp170048en.pdf)

These cases, however, concern children living in their own country, not another, so they are not directly applicable to your plan.  Furthermore, the conditions identified by the court that lead to a right for the parent to stay are not clear to me, nor is it clear how one would invoke this right if it does exist.

You may therefore want to speak with an Irish immigration lawyer or an immigrants' rights organization.  A web search turned up a lot of support organizations for Irish immigrants in the US, but also several Irish solicitors and [the Immigrant Council of Ireland](https://www.immigrantcouncil.ie/information-line).

Comment: Hi Martin, my father was born in the UK